# How to find all Google Docs (or Sheets) with comments?

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive, google-docs

In Google Docs/Sheets, when making a copy of a file, the comments don't get copied over. There is a plugin (*Copy Comments*) that makes a copy-with-comments for Docs, but it's one document at a time, which is really painful if you have a huge number of files to work through.

Thus, if you want to make a copy of a large number of files, it makes sense to:

- copy the entire thing over using Drive's built-in copy functionality or the *Folder Copy* plugin
- use the *Multiple File Rename* plugin to get rid of the 'Copy of ' prefix
- find the original documents that had comments, and use the *Copy Comments* plugin solely on them

Is there any way, via plugin, script, Google Sheet or whatnot, to check which documents in a set of folders have comments in them?

Comment: Would you please clarify... what is the specific process that you have in mind when you say " when making a copy of a file, the comments don't get copied over.". In Google sheets, the "File>Make a copy" command includes a checkbox option "Copy comments" - this includes comments in the copied spreadsheet.

Comment: Is this topic any help [To copy the cell text and the comments to another sheet using google apps script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33604330/1330560)